# How to get gross from Dbpedia with SPARQL

Tags: xml, r, sparql, dbpedia

I tried to get the gross from dbpedia with sparql query but I couldn't.
My code is

```
library(SPARQL)
endpoint <- 'http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql'
options <- NULL
prefix <- c("db","http://dbpedia.org/resource/")

sparql_prefix <- "PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
"

q <- paste(sparql_prefix,
           'SELECT ?actor ?movie  ?gross
           WHERE {
           ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> .
           ?m rdfs:label ?movie .
           FILTER(LANG(?movie) = "en")

           ?m dbo:gross ?a .
           ?a rdfs:label ?gross .
            FILTER(DATATYPE(?gross) = xsd:double)

           ?m dbp:starring ?a .
           ?a rdfs:label ?actor .
           FILTER(LANG(?actor) = "en")

           }')

results <- SPARQL(endpoint,q,ns=prefix,extra=options)$results
```

but returned a blank data.frame

Do you have any idea how to get the gross ??

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films gives the following message at the moment: 'The web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time. 
We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused.'

Comment: For what it's worth, langMatches(lang(?foo),"en") should usually be preferred to lang(?foo) = "en".  The former will get regional variants, like "en-US", whereas the latter won't.  While it's usually not a huge issue, movie titles could actually be one place it's an important point, since movies might be released in different places with different names.

Answer (score 3):

1. The value of `dbo:gross` is not a node, it doesn't make sense to use `rdfs:label` on it. Instead, it's directly a value.
2. The type of `dbo:gross` is not `xsd:double`, it's usually `<http://dbpedia.org/datatype/usDollar>`, but some movies use another currency.

So, the fixed query could look something like:

```sql
SELECT ?actor ?movie  ?gross 
WHERE {
  ?m dc:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_films> .
  ?m rdfs:label ?movie .
  FILTER(LANG(?movie) = "en")

  ?m dbo:gross ?gross .

  ?m dbp:starring ?a .
  ?a rdfs:label ?actor .
  FILTER(LANG(?actor) = "en")
}
```

Keep in mind that this query will only list movies that have both a `dbo:gross` and at least one `dbp:starring`. If that's not what you want, consider using `OPTIONAL`.

Comment: I noticed that you used "language: none" on your code block.  I've found that "language: sql"  actually works pretty well for SPARQL:  the right keywords are usually highlighted, and strings and numbers get treated as you'd expect.